# I cant see my web page from mobile devices

Tags: http-status-code-404

When trying to see my web sight form any mobile device i get a

"The request url /mobile/index.html was not found in our server. 404. Not found error was encountered while trying to us an error document to handle the request."

www.hectorsv.com

I don't have the slightest clue what to do?

Comment: Somewhere there is a redirect to http://www.hectorsv.com/mobile/index.html happening for mobile devices.  Once you find out where, you'll fix your issue. Without knowing more about your setup/code, its hard to tell where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is redirecting to this:

[link](http://hectorsv.com/mobile/index.html)

Which is a 404 Not Found Error because either the mobile folder doesn't exist or the index.html file inside the mobile folder doesn't exist